# Is there an analogue of Kan's $\operatorname{Ex}^\infty$ functor for $(\infty,n)$-categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

$\DeclareMathOperator\Ex{Ex}$Kan's $\Ex^\infty$ functor (see [Why is Kan's $Ex^\infty$ functor useful?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324738/why-is-kans-ex-infty-functor-useful)) $\Ex^\infty\colon\mathsf{sSets}\to\mathsf{Kan}$ produces a Kan complex from a simplicial set in a combinatorial way, providing an $\infty$-groupoidification functor $\Ex^\infty\colon\mathsf{Cats}_{\infty}\to\mathsf{Grpd}_\infty$ in the context of $\infty$-categories (modelled as quasicategories). In addition, it comes with a natural transformation $\mathfrak{c}\colon\operatorname{id}_{\mathsf{sSets}}\Rightarrow\Ex^\infty$ whose components
$$\mathfrak{c}_{X}\colon X_{\bullet}\to\Ex^\infty_\bullet(X)$$
are weak homotopy equivalences.

It is then natural to wonder if there exist analogues of $\Ex^\infty$ with Kan complexes (which model $\infty$-groupoids, i.e. $(\infty,0)$-categories) replaced with general $(\infty,n)$-categories; this would be a functor
$$Q_\bullet\colon\mathsf{sSets}\to\mathsf{Cats}_{(\infty,n)}$$
producing an $(\infty,n)$-category from a simplicial set, and restricting (in some suitable sense, depending on the chosen model for $(\infty,n)$-categories) to the left adjoint $$\mathsf{triv}_n\colon\mathsf{Cats}_{(\infty,n)}\to\mathsf{Cats}_{(\infty,n-1)}$$
to the inclusion $\iota_n\colon\mathsf{Cats}_{(\infty,n-1)}\hookrightarrow\mathsf{Cats}_{(\infty,n)}$.

For the $n=1$ case (see [Dmitri Pavlov's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/373977) to [A combinatorial approximation functor sSet->qCat](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52205/a-combinatorial-approximation-functor-sset-qcat/373977#373977)), one can essentially just pick a simplicial set $X_\bullet$ and apply $\mathrm{Ex}^\infty$ to its morphism simplicial sets.

Similarly, is there a combinatorial/non-recursive (in the sense described [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255125)) analogue of the pair $(\mathrm{Ex}^\infty,\mathfrak{c})$ for:

- $(\infty,2)$-categories [defined as in Kerodon](https://kerodon.net/tag/01W4)? (I guess one could perhaps repeat Dmitri's strategy with $\mathrm{Q}_\bullet$ instead of $\Ex^\infty$, at least as long as there are analogues of $\mathfrak{C}\dashv\mathrm{N}^\mathrm{hc}_\bullet$ for categories enriched in quasicategories and $(\infty,2)$-categories, or perhaps by using $2$-fold complete Segal spaces instead of these, or (…).)
- $(\infty,n)$-categories (including $(\infty,\infty)$-categories) modelled as complicial sets?

Comment: Model categories have functorial fibrant replacements.

Comment: For complicial sets, you can presumably just forget the markings and then apply the usual $Ex^\infty$ functor

Comment: @FernandoMuro I've edited the question to be more explicit about this: I was instead hoping for a more combinatorial/non-recursive construction (maybe a right adjoint functor or a colimit of right adjoint functors, along the lines of Tim's question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255125))

Comment: @TimCampion Is there a (combinatorial, in the sense of your question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255125)) construction that instead starts with a simplicial set and then builds a complicial/comical set from it, though?

Comment: @Emily I'm confused by the question in [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413366/is-there-an-analogue-of-kans-operatornameex-infty-functor-for-infty-n#comment1059679_413366) because it seems to go in the opposite direction to the main question. The answer is: Sure, you can turn a simplicial set $X$ into a complicial set $X^\sharp$ by marking everything. If $X$ is a Kan complex, then $X^\sharp$ is fibrant.

Comment: @TimCampion Hi Tim, sorry for the confusion! The question I'm wondering about is the following: "Ex^∞ works as ∞-groupoidification Cats_∞ → Grpd_∞, but it is defined in the whole of sSets, making an ∞-groupoid out of any simplicial set. However, here Grpd_∞ is really Cats_(∞,0), so we could ask the same question for Cats_(∞,n+1) and Cats_(∞,n). In this sense, is there an analogue of Ex^∞ for (∞,n)-categories, starting with a simplicial set and building an (∞,n)-category out of it, where we choose to model these as complicial or comical sets?"

Comment: Is the assignment $X\mapsto X^\sharp$ a good analogue of Ex^∞ in this sense for n=∞, i.e. for (∞,∞)-categories? (Incidentally, does $X^\sharp$ being fibrant means it is a saturated complicial set?). Also, thanks for your reply and sorry for the confusion again!

Comment: Ah, I think I understand the question now. Certainly it's going to depend on your model. I'm tempted to guess that for $n$-fold complete Segal spaces, you could apply $Ex^\infty$ to just one simplicial direction. For complicial sets it seems difficult. (And yes, I meant that $X^\sharp$ is a saturated complicial set.)

Comment: @TimCampion Hi Tim, thanks for the explanation! (And sorry for taking a while to reply)